# Free IntelliSense for C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, intellisense

Does anybody here know any free IntelliSense tool available for C++ which is atleast 50% of the features of [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) (Which of course is not free)? Basically I want my intellisense to work without loading my full workspace/solution? I had seen Visual Assist and it provides this feature.

Answer (score 8):

Support these guys as they spent considerable time writing this excellent tool and just buy it.

For free alternatives you can check [CTags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and a [plugin for VS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/dstags.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into the EnvironmentEvents module in your Visual Studio macros:

```
Dim curWord As String
Private Sub TextDocumentKeyPressEvents_AfterKeyPress(ByVal Keypress As String, ByVal Selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection, ByVal InStatementCompletion As Boolean) Handles TextDocumentKeyPressEvents.AfterKeyPress

    If (InStr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_", Keypress)) Then

        curWord = curWord + Keypress

        If (curWord.Length > 2) Then
            'AutoCompleteFromFile()
            curWord = ""
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CompleteWord")
        End If
    Else
        curWord = ""
    End If

End Sub
```